# Auto calculation of number of students passing and failing the test using excel sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel sheet, In that, I need to calculate how many students are passing and how many are failing the exams.

**Let us assume I have 30 Questions that means 30 columns and 200 students means 200 rows.
60% is the minimum criteria for passing the exams.**

I have another sheet which holds the Answer key along with the question that holds 30 columns for 30 Questions and 1 row for all the answers.

I need the number of students who are through to the exam.

Example:
**The students are given multiple choice questions and here the following data is achieved after the conduction of exam in excel sheet:**

RolNo---Q1------Q2------Q3------Q4----Q5

101-----abc---pqr--xyz---uif---lkm

102-----rft---pqr--bgh---uif---wer

103-----rft---pqr--bgh---uif---wer

104-----abc---pqr--bgh---uif---wer

105-----rft---pqr--bgh---uif---wer

**Now we have another sheet which holds the answer**

***Answer key sheet***:

Q1------Q2------Q3------Q4----Q5

abc-----pqr------xyz------uif----wer

**Note**

4 marks for each question right.

-1 negative marking for incorrect answer.

0 for leaving the question that means no negative marking.

60% is the minimum criteria for passing the exams

I want all the calculations to occur in the sheet and I can get the details how many are passing and failing.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have tried the EXACT function  to compare with the answer but not getting how to go about it

Comment: Is it possible to do without macros

Comment: Im sure you did more than just write EXACT in an empty cell? What EXACTly did you write?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we assume:

1. You have 3 worksheets sheet 1 of questions, sheet 2 of answer, and a results sheet
2. And we assume the Exam correct answer to first question is on the answers sheet in a2 and progresses to b2, b3 etc...
3. and we assume the student answers is on the questions sheet and start in A2 with the ID and B2 fir the first answer... then the following formula would work..

Note For A2 I just selected the 1st student ID and then filled down and then used the formula for B-end of questions.

`=IF(Question!B2="",0,IF(Question!B2=Answers!A$2,4,-1))`\

This formula basically states if the answer is blank use a 0 if the student answer matches the actual answer then 4, otherwise put a -1.

[image]
[image]

note that column G is the sum of B-F
[image]

Comment: I appreciate the work you did , Though I have a query don't you think I have to do a redundant work to write down the formulas for each answer , can you optimize it?

Comment: Once the formula is entered you can click the Back squre at the bottom of B2 and drag to the right release.  You could then write the formula for summing the results and then Click again and drag down for 200 rows and all cells filled in with totals.

Comment: Excel's a powerful tool for data analysis.  These are fundamental concepts in Excel.  I'd recommend a course on Excel if you plan on using it more often. Fundamental and Pivot tables.  I think you'll find those of value later.  Also, be sure to spot check the results for 20 of the 200 users;  to make sure it's doing what you'd expect!  10% sampling on data should be enough to identify potential issues.